# TabWidget activity

Tags: android

Is `TabWidget`. How to me under it to start `Activity`?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class FileM extends Activity {

    private TabHost mTabHost;

    private void setupTabHost() {
        mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        setupTabHost();
        mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.tab_divider);

        setupTab(new TextView(this), "Система");
        setupTab(new TextView(this), "Удаление");
        setupTab(new TextView(this), "Бэкап");
    }

    private void setupTab(final View view, final String tag) {
        View tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), tag);


        TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {return view;}
        });
        mTabHost.addTab(setContent);

    }
    private static View createTabView(final Context context, final String text) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tabs_bg, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
        tv.setText(text);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to start an activity under your tab...

```
 TabSpec ts1 = _tabHost.newTabSpec("Page1");
            Drawable a = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
            ts1.setIndicator("Test",a);
            ts1.setContent(new Intent(this,MyHome.class));
            _tabHost.addTab(ts1);
```

Comment: `private void setupTab(final View view, final String tag) {
        View tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), tag);
        
        TabSpec ts1 = mTabHost.newTabSpec("Page1");
        Drawable a = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
        ts1.setIndicator("Test",a);
        ts1.setContent(new Intent(this,uninstall.class));
        mTabHost.addTab(ts1);`

Comment: Tell where exactly it is necessary to insert a code. And that at me can't be started...

Comment: From look at my project. A code which you to me a distance, doesn't approach a little. Help to write correctly please. Very much I ask!http://narod.ru/disk/14319766001/TFile.rar.html

Comment: I know, how on another to make, as is specified here: http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html. But I need to use the code...